# Voltage of Arcing electricity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, electricity, voltage

In Star Wars, Count Dooku electrocutes both Anakin and Yoda at a distance of about 5m. Obviously this is not meant to be scientifically accurate as it is a fictional movie, but how much voltage would be required for such an arc in real life, and how do I calculate this, and the charge expended over a period of time for myself? (A rough explaination would be great if possible, I need to be able to calculate it not just give a number!) thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on electrical breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown).

Answer (score 0):

Breakdown voltage of dry air at 1 atmosphere between spherical electrodes is generally accepted to be of the order of 3.3kV per mm. With spikey electrodes and damp air its massively less but tricky to calculate with a formulae. Designers of power lines use past experience to calculate safety margins. Of course once you have got a spark going you can get really long ones with much lower voltage. Go on youtube and put in "high voltage sparks" for some lovely video examples. Warning - some are a bit gruesome involving actually "fried" humans and animals so don't look at the nasty ones if you are young or sensitive !